# C - Read and allocate an arbitrary array of strings

Tags: c, c89

I'm getting mad at a really simple function to read an array of strings given in input.
I also know how to read strings and put them into an array without writing a proper function (writing all thing in main() ).
This is the example I'm using.

I think that the main obstacle is to use properly the 3-star pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read(char ***a, int *len){
    scanf("%d", len);

    if(*len <= 0) return 1;

    *a = malloc(*len * sizeof(char *));
    if(*a == NULL) return 1;

    for(int i=0; i<*len; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(101 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", *a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int len, i;
    char **A;
    // read an array of strings
    if( read(&A, &len)) return 1;

    // DO SOMETHING

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%s\n", A[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a three-star programmer!

Comment: Why? What's not good about this?

Comment: Using `***` is generally not considered the cleanest of designs, particularly coming from an absolute beginner.

Comment: Things can get a little less confusing if you create local variables (`char **local_a; int local_len;`) and use those throughout the function. Then, before the function exits, assign them: `*a = local_a; *len = local_len;

Comment: So, no one need a function like this? @EOF

Comment: In this case, you might have a good reason to use three levels of indirection, since you want a variably sized array of strings, but when dealing with multiple indirection you need to always consider the type of the objects you are dealing with.

Comment: One way to eliminate the `***` would be to have the function return an array: `char ** read(int *len) {...}`

Comment: Another way to avoid the`***` is to use (and return) a (pointer to) struct, containing both the pointer and the number of (used) elements. BTW:`read()` is a *terrible name* for a function, it could be confused with the `read` systemcall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look out for two things: operator precedence and indirection level. Do enclose your variables in parenthesis if you don't know which operator has higher precedence than the other:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read(char ***a, int *len)
{
    scanf("%d", len);

    if (*len <= 0) return 1;

    *a = (char **)malloc(*len * sizeof(char *));
    if (*a == NULL) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i<*len; i++) {
        (*a)[i] = (char *)malloc(101 * sizeof(char)); // note this line
        scanf("%s", (*a)[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int len, i;
    char **A;
    // read an array of strings
    if (read(&A, &len)) return 1;

    // DO SOMETHING

    for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%s\n", A[i]);

    //system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copy pasted bugs!

Comment: @freestyle what are you talking about?

Comment: @H.S. That's not a bug, and I intentionally left it there for the OP to notice the difference between the two calls to malloc().

Comment: @freestyle I tested it 3 times. It's working fine on my system. If there is a problem in the code, tell me about it.

Comment: @machine_1: I didn't point out it as a bug but just a suggestion.

Comment: For example, input string more then 100 characters.

Comment: @freestyle Really? Are you serious? If the OP wants to protect against buffer overflow, that's his job. My answer addresses the problem in the question body.

Comment: @freestyle it works. Input string more than 100 chars is not concerned in this program.

Comment: @machine_1 thanks on this tips about managing pointers. The cast is not necessary as suggested above.